# Was würdest du mir zu sagen?

Tags: translation

I was looking for a translation for:

> What would you like me to say?

and was given "Was würdest du mir zu sagen?".

To me, that translates literally to:

> What would you say to me?

Which is correct and for what reasons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, "Was würdest du mir sagen?" (mind that the "zu" is wrong there) translates to "What would you say to me?.

I would translate "What would you like me to say?":

> Was möchtest du, dass ich sage.

I think in general the structure

> What [do you want | would you like...] me to [do | say | ask... ]

is in German

> Was [willst | möchtest...] du, dass ich [tue | sage | frage ...]

It's the same with

> I want you to go

becomes

> Ich will, dass du gehst

Comment: Thank you.  "dass ich sage" still sounds alien to me, which is why I couldn't get it.  "What would you like, that I say" doesn't feel right but I will learn to get used to it!

Answer (score 4):

[*"Was soll ich dazu sagen?"*](https://translate.google.com/#auto/de/What%20would%20you%20like%20me%20to%20say%3F) - Google Translate or other translation services fail here because of the English source grammar, where *me* and *to* had an ambiguous relation from a machine's view. Only on searching for a probably manually added idiomatic phrase *"What would you like me to do?"* the resulting translation gets it correct.

To find our way out of this we my split the originial to:

> What would you like? - *Was möchten Sie gerne?  Was hätten Sie gerne?*
>   Was should I say? - *Was soll ich sagen?*

This can be put together again to German

> Was hätten Sie gerne, dass ich sage? *or more idiomatic:* Was soll ich Ihrer Meinung nach sagen?

but probably we will mostly just hear the short version we already had from above:

> Was soll ich sagen?

Answer (score 3):

What would you like me to say.

My translation would be:

> Was möchtest du (denn), dass ich dazu sage.

or:

> Was soll ich deiner Meinung nach dazu sagen.

Comment: Das "dazu" ist falsch; es hat in der Frage keine Entsprechung.