# eine (Ergänzung-)Frage für den Satz "ich möchte bitte, dass du über dieses Thema redest"

Tags: phrase, sentence-structure

Ich habe den folgenden Satz:

> *Ich möchte bitte, dass du über dieses Thema redest*

Der dass-Satz wird als ein Objekt-Satz verwendet, er antwortet auf die Frage "Was möchte/möchtest ich/du?", und dazu hoffe ich keinen Fehler zu machen. Allerdings frage ich mich, wie kann ich eine (Ergänzung-)Frage für den Satz bilden? Ich habe ein bisschen darüber nachgedacht und am Ende drei Frage-Sätze gebildet, trotzdem bin ich nicht sicher, welche korrekt ist oder nicht - ehrlich gesagt, habe ich nie auf diese Wiese solche Fragen gestellt - deswegen bitte ich jemanden um Hilfe. Die Frage, die ich gebildet habe, sind:

> *Worüber möchtest du, dass ich rede?*
>
> *Was möchtest du, worüber ich rede?*
>
> *Möchtest du, worüber ich rede?*

Answer (score 1):

> Ich möchte bitte, dass du über dieses Thema redest.

Es scheint naheliegend zu sein, auch in der Rückfrage einen Objektsatz zu verwenden. Das ist aber falsch, denn im Fragesatz wird das Objekt ja bereits durch das Fragewort gebildet.

> Worüber möchtest du, dass ich rede?
>
> Was möchtest du, worüber ich rede?
>
> Möchtest du, worüber ich rede?

Richtig ist:

> **Was** genau (über dieses Thema) möchten Sie wissen?
>
> **Worüber** genau soll ich sprechen?

Es spielt keine Rolle, wie die ursprüngliche Bitte formuliert ist, ob mit Objektsatz oder ohne. Wesentlich ist, dass der selbst konstruierte Satz das gefragte Objekt beinhaltet.

Die Gegenbitte verwendet einen Objektsatz:

> Bitte sagen Sie mir, über was genau ich sprechen soll.

Comment: ich verstehe, was du geschrieben hast, allerdings habe ich nicht begriffen, wie das Objekt bereits durch das Fragewort im Satz "Möchtest du, worüber ich rede?" gebildet wird, außerdem habe ich folgendes gefunden: http://www.mittendrin.org/media/2724/mk.10,35-45_20.10.02.pdf (36)

Comment: hier http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15625/was-w%C3%BCrdest-du-mir-zu-sagen schreibt Takkat "Was hätten Sie gerne, dass ich sage?", ist das nicht ähnlich?

Comment: "Möchtest du, worüber ich rede?" klingt meinetwegen ebenso, wie "verstehen sie, was ich meine?" zu sagen, oder denke ich falsch? Ich bin Italiener und ich versuche immer und immer richtig Deu sprechen, und auf Ita sind solche Frage möglich, wie z.B. "Che vuoi che dica?" oder "Di cosa vuole che parli?" oder "Cosa vuole che faccia?"...

Comment: @mle: Das Fragewort ersetzt das Objekt, nach dem gefragt wird. Der Fragesatz *Wen hast du getroffen?* lässt sich zum fragenden Aussagesatz *Du hast wen getroffen?* umformulieren. Du siehst hier sicher besser, dass *wen* das Akkusativobjekt ist, nach dem gefragt wird. *Du hast Susanne getroffen?*  Zur Bibelstelle: Das ist als typische Bibelsprache erkennbar, weil heute keiner mehr so spricht außer Pastoren auf der Kanzel. Takkat schrieb selbst "Was soll ich Ihrer Meinung nach sagen?" sei "more idiomatic". Ich würde seine andere Formulierung niemals benutzen, es ist vermutlich dialektabhängig.

Comment: Der Unterschied zwischen *verstehen Sie, was ich meine* und *möchtest du, worüber ich rede?* ist, dass *möchte* ein weiteres Verb oder Substantiv erfordert, das gemocht wird. Zum Beispiel *Möchtest du (überhaupt) **hören**, worüber ich rede?". *(è questo) che vuoi che dica* kann man wohl mit *(ist es) das, was du willst, was ich sagen soll* übersetzen. Klingt im Deutschen aber furchtbar holprig, da würde man mehrere Sätze draus machen. *Ist es das, was du willst? Das, was ich sagen soll?*

Comment: wow... sehr interessant, das wusste ich nicht und ich danke dir für die Erklärungen und die Beispiele... allerdings, hast du eine quelle wie canoo o duden o etwas anderes mir zu verlinken? Es heißt nicht, daß ich an dir nicht glaube ;)... noch mal, danke!!

Comment: Eine aufgeschriebene Regel für etwas zu finden, was es **nicht** gibt (oder was zumindest nicht idiomatisch ist) ist schwierig. Für was genau suchst du eine Regel?

Comment: "Worüber möchtest du, dass ich rede?" sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Welcher Dialekt?

Comment: Ich schliesse mich Gerhard an... als Grazer würde ich das so sagen und schreiben.